# Configure iOS camera parameters to avoid banding in video preview

Tags: ios5, camera

I have and application OpenCV based to process images.

I need a clean image to process data. When I´m in a zone with fluorescent light, it appear in the image some banding. In Android, I solved that problem configuring the camera parameter ANTIBANDING_50HZ, [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setAntibanding%28java.lang.String%29) is the reference, and it looks and process right.

But in [apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html), I cannot find a way to avoid this problem. I have been adjusting some options to improve the image, but their are not solving the banding.

My camera is configured using this code:

```
- (BOOL) setupCaptureSessionParameters
{
    NSLog(@"--- Configure Camera options...");
    /*
     * Create capture session with optimal size to OpenCV processing
     */
    captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;

    AVCaptureDevice *cameraBack =[self videoDeviceWithPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];

    if ([cameraBack lockForConfiguration:nil])
    {
        NSLog(@"lockForConfiguration...");
        // No autofocus
        if ( [cameraBack isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeLocked])
        {
            cameraBack.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusModeLocked;

        }
        // Focus center image always
        if ( [cameraBack isFocusPointOfInterestSupported])
        {
            cameraBack.focusPointOfInterest = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
        }
        // Autoexpose color is have a several change of lights
        if ( [cameraBack isExposurePointOfInterestSupported] )
        {
            cameraBack.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure;
        }
        // Auto adjust white balance is user aim to a reflectant surface
        if ( [cameraBack isWhiteBalanceModeSupported:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeContinuousAutoWhiteBalance])
        {
            cameraBack.whiteBalanceMode = AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeContinuousAutoWhiteBalance;
        }
        // Only Focus far
        if ( [cameraBack isAutoFocusRangeRestrictionSupported])
        {
            cameraBack.autoFocusRangeRestriction = AVCaptureAutoFocusRangeRestrictionFar;
        }
        // Choose best rate depending preset
        AVCaptureDeviceFormat *bestFormat = nil;
        AVFrameRateRange *bestFrameRateRange = nil;

        for ( AVCaptureDeviceFormat *format in [cameraBack formats] )
        {
            for ( AVFrameRateRange *range in format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges )
            {
                if ( range.maxFrameRate > bestFrameRateRange.maxFrameRate )
                {
                    bestFormat = format;
                    bestFrameRateRange = range;
                }
            }
        }
        if (bestFormat)
        {
            cameraBack.activeFormat = bestFormat;
            cameraBack.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = bestFrameRateRange.minFrameDuration;
            cameraBack.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = bestFrameRateRange.maxFrameDuration;
        }
        [cameraBack unlockForConfiguration];
         NSLog(@"unlockForConfiguration!");
    }
}
```

Pictures:
[image: Banding I]
[image: No Banding I with external light]
[image: Banding II]

Comment: Core Image (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html) offers various options to let you prepare the image after taking it with the camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow Apple´s documentation about [CIFilter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Filter_Category_Keys)

Android and IOS are very different about Camera Parameters. Android allows you to customise camera parameter to avoid banding. In th other hand, in IOS you need to use to work with CIFilter class. Android and IOS works in different directions.